# What does these lines indicates in jsp file?:

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

I have a jsp file and in the very beginning of the jsp i have below lines of code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

If `i remove the above lines then page is not rendered in IE but it renders in FF`. Please can someone explain what the above lines are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with JSP, it is only "understood" by IE, it is a non-standard addition from Microsoft, if you have code only for IE, then you use a conditional HTML inclusion:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> ... <![endif]-->
```

Other browsers won't see the code because what they will "see" is a standard HTML comment `<!-- ... -->`

The conditionals `[if lt IE 7]`, `[if IE 8]` etc. are somewhat self-explanatory: `[if lt IE 7]` means "if IE version is Lower Than 7 then add this" or `[if IE 8]` "if IE version is 8 then add this"

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. what does below line indicates? <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Comment: "no-js lt-ie`0 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" are just CSS class selectors, this just means that these classes are going to be applied. For instance, the line `<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <![endif]-->` means "if IE version is 9, then these CSS classes are going to be applied" about `xml:lang`, `xmlns:fb`,  (XML attributes) means that you're trying to generate an XHTML document

Answer (score 0):

They are called **Conditional Comments**. Its used to detect the version of Windows Internet Explorer

Get the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. what does below line indicates?  <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Answer (score 0):

> what does below line indicates?

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" 
      xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

It means the following:

- This in an HTML document.
- The "language" for the document content is English
- The following (style) classes apply to the document ... "no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7".  These classes are possibly defined in a stylesheet and/or referenced in javascript used in the page.
- If you see "fb" as a XML namespace prefix in a tag name, it means "facebook.com/2008/fbml".  That looks like a Facebook-defined XML schema.